# Mergesort - std::bad_alloc thrown when trying to assign vector

Tags: c++, mergesort, bad-alloc

Good afternoon ladies and gents. So, it is not my day for errors. Implementing Mergesort (not in-place) in C++, and I'm having real trouble with the code, with no idea why. The second-to-last line of the `mergeSort()` function assigns the result of the `merge()` to a vector of ints, `result`. This line (the actual allocation, not the function) throws a `bad_alloc` error, and I have no idea why.

The internet suggests that `bad_alloc` is mostly thrown due to out-of-memory errors, but this cannot be the case as the first time its called is on a vector of 500 ints, which should be nowhere near too much memory (what is that, like 2 Kb on a 32-bit int?). I assume I'm doing something silly and incorrect for C++, but I don't know what. I tried calling `what()` on the exception, but that just returns its name. The code:

```
vector<int> Sorting::mergeSort(vector<int> A) {

    // If the length of A is 0 or 1, it is sorted.
    if(A.size() < 2) return A;

    // Find the mid-point of the list.
    int midpoint = A.size() / 2;

    // Declare the left/right vectors.
    vector<int> left, right;

    // Declare the return vector.
    vector<int> result (A.size());

    for(int i = 0; i < midpoint; ++i) {
        left.push_back(A.at(i));
    }

    for(int i = midpoint; i < A.size(); ++i) {
        right.push_back(A.at(i));
    }

    left = mergeSort(left);
    right = mergeSort(right);
    result = merge(left, right);

    return result;

}


vector<int> merge(vector<int> left, vector<int> right) {

    vector<int> result;

    while(left.size() > 0 && right.size() > 0) {

        if(left.front() <= right.front()) {
            result.push_back(left.front());
            left.erase(left.begin());
        } else {
            result.push_back(right.front());
            right.erase(right.begin());
        }
    }

    if(left.size() > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < left.size(); ++i) {
            result.push_back(left.at(i));
        }
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < right.size(); ++i) {
            result.push_back(right.at(i));
        }
    }

}
```

If I re-write the `merge` function to just take a reference to `result` and edit it during the function, it works fine, but I wanted to keep the code as close as possible to the 'standard' psuedo-code given for merge-sort.

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: I understand why you dont want to use references, but i think you should reconsider this. And to make the code even better and faster, instead of passing vectors around, why not work only with indexes? So the recursive calls would get just the start and end index and a reference to the vector being sorted.

Comment: Because that is an in-place mergesort, and will be coded later. I'm writing myself a library of sorting algorithms. For... fun. Yeah, I need help.

Comment: Coding something for fun is good :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `Merge` function, `vector<int> result` is not being returned.

Comment: @Stephen: You should use compiler settings that tell you about this (e.g. `-Wreturn-type` and maybe `-Werror=...` for GCC).

Comment: Is it ironic that I just helped someone earlier today to find the compiler settings to make what I just did an error when he was compiling his code? =D. I'll go get Netbeans (yes, I'm coding in Netbeans! Don't hurt me!) to turn those on, thanks Georg.